# Dataset Variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dataset

It's the first time I use powershell and I try to print data from a dataset :

I stored the data of an sql table into a dataset then I tried that (I found that code on another topic):

```
foreach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables.Rows)
         { 
          write-host "$($Row[0])"
          write-host "$($Row[1])"


        }
```

and it prints me the first 2 columns and the dataset, it seems normal but when I try that :

```
foreach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
         { 
          write-host "$($Row[0])"
          write-host "$($Row[1])"


        }
```

I got the exact same thing for the ouput despite the "Tables[0]" instead of "Tables",  Why do we need the variable "Table" ?

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: PowerShell is based on .NET framework, and in .NET, `[]` is the `index operator`. It selects objects from indexed collections, such as arrays and
hash tables. Since index starts from **0**, hence `$Tables[0]` selects the first element of `$Dataset`. In your PowerShell console, see `$Dataset.Tables.Count` to see the length of `$Dataset` and `Get-Help about_Operators` to know more about operators.

If length of `$Dataset` is 1, then `$Tables[1]` wont yield you anything, since it wont exist in the context.

Comment: A DataSet contains a collection of Tables. To loop through the data in one of these tables, you use `$Dataset.Tables[$index]` or user the table name like `$Dataset.Tables["TableName"]` to target the table you want get the Rows for. If the Dataset contains just one table even the `foreach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables.Rows)` works but it is highly recommended to always pinpoint the desired table using its index or name.